# Does versus will--Can "does" be followed by an ing verb and "will"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Such as :

```
 does staring at this will hurt my eyes? 

 does teaching will make me more patient?
```

Is it that we can use only one helping verb in a verb phrase?

I am not technically sure, but the sentences appears and sounds better with "will" omitted from the above examples.

Comment: You can definitely follow "does" with a verb.

"Does falling down the stairs count as an accident?"
"Does staring at the sun hurt your eyes?"

However, I can't think of an occasion where "will" would fit.

Comment: Two helping verbs *can be* used in some grammatical English sentences, but not *do* and *will*.

Answer (score 2):

You should use one or the other, not both.  The implications are different, also.

> Will staring at this hurt my eyes?

"*If* I do this, will it have these consequences?"

> Does staring at this hurt my eyes

"I do this. Is it the cause of my eye pain?"

Your version is not grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

The rule you need for questions is:

If there's an auxiliary verb put it in front of the subject to make the question. If there's no auxiliary, put *DO* in front of the subject to make the question. Don't use *DO* if there's another auxiliary.

> does staring at this will hurt my eyes?
>
> does teaching will make me more patient?

The subjects in your sentences are *staring* and *teaching*. The auxiliary you should have is *will* (if there's another auxiliary, we never need *DO*!). To make the question we move the auxiliary in front of the subject like this:

- **Will** staring at this hurt my eyes?
- **Will** teaching make me more patient?

[There are some special questions called subject questions, which are different. You don't need to worry about those - because students almost never make mistakes with subject questions!]

Hope this helps!